# How to make a button that takes its background shape android

Tags: android, button, background, shapes

i just want a button that takes the shape of its background 
for example i have this image :

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXc6L.png)

and i have put it as a background for an ImageButton what i want is that the button takes the same shape and not remain rectangular

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK by android design all the views are rectangular. You can extend a view class, define a closed path for your image in `onSizeChanged` (using the boundary of solid part and maths alongwith width and height of view) and override its `onTouch` to respond only touches which fall in the closed path defined above. So finally you will be able to realize the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

While Virendra Singh's answer is correct, I feel like using paths might be too difficult in a generic case.

To handle all cases you would need a per pixel test. Per pixel test draws the view and tests the touched pixel if it's clickable. The code is very short:

```
public class BitmapButton extends Button {

    private final Bitmap bitmap;
    private final Canvas canvas;

    public BitmapButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        bitmap.setPixel(0, 0, 0); // reset pixel
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(-event.getX(), -event.getY());
        draw(canvas); // draw only the touched pixel
        canvas.restore();
        // pass touch events when the pixel is clickable
        return Color.alpha(bitmap.getPixel(0, 0)) > 0 && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```